# A question regarding the nuances of functions within MatLab

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, vector

When I run this piece of code:

```
dx = 4/(nx-1);
dy = 2/(ny-1);
phinew(2:ny-1,2:nx-1) = ((dy^2*(phiold(1:ny-2,2:nx-1)+phiold(3:ny,2:nx-1))+dx^2*(phiold(2:ny-1,1:nx-2)+phiold(2:ny-1,3:nx)))/(2*(dx^2+dy^2))-poissonf);
```

Within my code, the piece of code operates correctly, taking an input of an `nx` by `ny` matrix and outputting a `nx` by `ny` matrix. When I run the following code in the exact same position however:

```
phinew = Smoothing(phiold,poissonf,nx,ny)
```

Where the function "Smoothing" is defined as:

```
function [phinew,dx,dy] = Smoothing(phiold,poissonf,nx,ny)
        dx = 4/(nx-1);
        dy = 2/(ny-1);
        phinew(2:ny-1,2:nx-1) = ((dy^2*(phiold(1:ny-2,2:nx-1)+phiold(3:ny,2:nx-1))+dx^2*(phiold(2:ny-1,1:nx-2)+phiold(2:ny-1,3:nx)))/(2*(dx^2+dy^2))-poissonf);
end
```

The function returns a `nx-1` by `ny-1` matrix for an `nx` by `ny` input.

I cannot wrap my head around why this is occurring at all. The output matrix is the exact same as it should be, except the last column and row are missing entirely. My code is iterative and so requires these to be of the same size, so I cannot move on until this issue is resolved.

Thank you for your time and your help. You people are life-savers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your code in the command window, `phinew` already exists. In your command window, do `clear phinew` before you pasting in those three lines, and you'll find that `phinew` is then `nx-1` by `ny-1`, as you get from your function.

If you want to force your function to return `nx` by `ny`, put `phinew = zeros(nx,ny);` at the start of the function, or set the last column and row to whatever you want them to be.

EDIT: Responding you your comment "why [does the RHS of the main assignment output] a 48x48 matrix? Directly before the command is run phiold, phinew and poissonf are all 50x50."

I don't think `poissonf` is 50x50: that would lead to the error `Matrix dimensions must agree`, because `poissonf` is being added to the rest of the expression which is part of `phiold`, so I'll ignore `poissonf` in the following.

The RHS is always `ny-2` by `nx-2`, even on the first iteration. You can see this by assigning the RHS to an intermediate variable, e.g. `phipiece = ...` and checking `size(phipiece)`. The reason `phinew` (if created anew) is 49x49 is because it is assigned to `(2:ny-1,2:nx-1)`, which will create a `ny-1` by `nx-1` matrix and leave the first row and column as zero.

If you use `phinew = zeros(nx,ny);` first, then the first and last rows and columns are left as zero.

Comment: As a follow up: any idea as to why on the second iteration (my function is recursive and halves the size each time) the section `(dy^2*(phiold(1:ny-2,2:nx-1)+phiold(3:ny,2:nx-1))+dx^2*(phiold(2:ny-1,1:nx-2)+phiold(2:ny-1,3:nx)))/(2*(dx^2+dy^2))` outputs a 48x48 matrix? Directly before the command is run phiold, phinew and poissonf are all 50x50